# How to connect cells in a table using tikzpicture and tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am trying to make a table look that like an accounting debit and credit sheet. The table i want to make is look likes this:
[image: Expected Table]

but i can only get as far as the table format and content because the code i used to make the arrow doesn't work, it return the

> "Cannot parse this coordinate error"

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
    \begin{table}[H] \centering
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc|ccc|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{NH Trung Ương} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{NH Thương Mại} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Doanh Nghiệp, \ldots} \\
         \cline{1-2}                             \cline{4-5}                          \cline{7-8}
FR         & \tikzmark{d}{RR}     & &\tikzmark{c}{RR}  &\tikzmark{b}{D} & &\tikzmark{a}{D}              &Loan        \\
Debts & C                         & & ER               &                & & C                           &            \\
IOU   &                           & &Loans             &                & &                             &C 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, yshift=.25\baselineskip, shorten >=.5pt, shorten <=.5pt]
    \draw [->] ({pic cs:a}) -- to ({pic cs:b});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: The what i get table]

I don't know what went wrong with my code, i follow the answer from this post [How to draw such arrows in the table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248447/how-to-draw-such-arrows-in-the-table).
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters, there's no need to enclose the coordinates with curly braces in your case, so you should remove them. Also, I suggest you remove the call for the library and add a definition for a newcommand instead.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\tikzmark[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture, anchor=base] \node (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc|ccc|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{NH Trung Ương} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{NH Thương Mại} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Doanh Nghiệp, \ldots} \\
         \cline{1-2}                             \cline{4-5}                          \cline{7-8}
FR         & \tikzmark{d}{RR}     & &\tikzmark{c}{RR}  &\tikzmark{b}{D} & &\tikzmark{a}{D}              &Loan        \\
Debts & C                         & & ER               &                & & C                           &            \\
IOU   &                           & &Loans             &                & &                             &C 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, yshift=.25\baselineskip, ->, shorten >=.5pt, shorten <=.5pt]
    \draw (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding `anchor=base` in `tikzmark` definition for better alignment of marked items.